# Tic Tac Toe c++ Agrid doesn't reset

Tags: c++

I am a beginner programmer.I have built a tic tac toe game using c++. The game is working fine until the user is prompted to repeat. This where the problem is. The program doesn't loop correctly. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
char matrix[10] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9' };
void display();
int checkwin();
int restarter();

int main(){
    char repeat;
    do {


    string playername, player1, player2;
    int winner = 0;
    char mark = 0;
    int number = 0;
    int player = 1;
    char choice = 0;
    cout << "Player 1 please enter your name: ";
    getline(cin, player1);
    cout << "Player 2 please enter your name: ";
    getline(cin, player2);
    while (winner == 0)
    {
        display();
        if (player % 2)
        {
            playername = player1;
        }
        else
            playername = player2;
        cout << playername << " " << "Please choose a number you want" << endl;
        cin >> number;
        if (player % 2)
        {
            mark = 'X';
        }
        else
            mark = 'O';
        if (number == 1 && matrix[1] == '1')
        {
            matrix[1] = mark;
        }
        else if (number == 2 && matrix[2] == '2')
        {
            matrix[2] = mark;
        }
        else if (number == 3 && matrix[3] == '3')
        {
            matrix[3] = mark;
        }
        else if (number == 4 && matrix[4] == '4')
        {
            matrix[4] = mark;
        }
        else if (number == 5 && matrix[5] == '5')
        {
            matrix[5] = mark;
        }
        else if (number == 6 && matrix[6] == '6')
        {
            matrix[6] = mark;
        }
        else if (number == 7 && matrix[7] == '7')
        {
            matrix[7] = mark;
        }
        else if (number == 8 && matrix[8] == '8')
        {
            matrix[8] = mark;
        }
        else if (number == 9 && matrix[9] == '9')
        {
            matrix[9] = mark;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "WRONG MOVE!";
            player--;
            cin.ignore();
            cin.get();
        }
        winner = checkwin();
        player++;
        display();
        if (winner == 1)
        {
            cout << playername << " " << "WON!" << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "Its a draw!" << endl;
    }
    cout << "do u wana repeat?" << endl;
    cin >> repeat;

} while (repeat == 'Y');

    system("pause");
    return 0;
} 




void display()
{
    system("CLS");
    cout << "======= Welcome to You Tic and I Tac Your Toe =======" << endl;
    cout << "=======               Ivan                    =======" << endl;
    cout << "=======                &                      =======" << endl;
    cout << "=======              Mostafa                  =======" << endl;
    cout << "=====================================================" << endl;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "PLAYER 1 [X]    PLAYER 2 [O]" << endl;
    cout << "   |   |  " << endl;
    cout << " " << matrix[1] <<" | "<<matrix[2]<<" | "<< matrix[3] << endl;
    cout << "___|___|____" << endl;
    cout << "   |   |" << endl;
    cout << " " << matrix[4] <<" | "<<matrix[5]<<" | "<< matrix[6] << endl;
    cout << "___|___|____" << endl;
    cout << "   |   |" << endl;
    cout << " " << matrix[7] <<" | "<<matrix[8]<<" | " << matrix[9] << endl;
    cout << "   |   |" << endl;
}

int checkwin()
{
    if (matrix[1] == matrix[2] && matrix[2] == matrix[3])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (matrix[4] == matrix[5] && matrix[5] == matrix[6])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (matrix[7] == matrix[8] && matrix[8] == matrix[9])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (matrix[1] == matrix[4] && matrix[4] == matrix[7])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (matrix[2] == matrix[5] && matrix[5] == matrix[8])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (matrix[3] == matrix[6] && matrix[6] == matrix[9])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (matrix[2] == matrix[5] && matrix[5] == matrix[8])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (matrix[3] == matrix[5] && matrix[5] == matrix[7])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (matrix[1] == matrix[5] && matrix[5] == matrix[9])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (matrix[1] != '1' && matrix[2] != '2' && matrix[3] != '3' && matrix[4] != '4' && matrix[5] != '5' && matrix[6] != '6' && matrix[7] != '7' && matrix[8] != '8' && matrix[9] != '9')
        return 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you be more specific? What do you mean with doesn´t loop correctly? Please, check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't clearing your matrix after the game is won. Your matrix is a global variable, so it is created at the beginning of the program, and is not destroyed until the program stops. When you loop, all of the local variables created in the loop are destroyed, but not global variables. You need to manually clear this array. A function like this:

```
void clearMatrix()
{
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
                matrix[i] = '0'+i;
}
```

would clear the matrix if you execute it in the appropriate place.

```
int main(){
    char repeat;
    do {

    clearMatrix();
    string playername, player1, player2;
    int winner = 0;
    char mark = 0;
    ...
}
```

If you call this clearMatrix() function at the beginning of your do-while loop, your matrix will be reset every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "Player 1 please enter your name: ";
    cin >> player1;
    cout << "Player 2 please enter your name: ";
    cin >> player2;
```

note that you can use "cin" instead of using "getline" to avoid an error when typing the names again.

also do this:

```
else
            cout << "Its a draw!" << endl;
    }
     clearMatrix();
    cout << "do u wanna repeat?" << endl;
    cin >> repeat;


}
```

as you have to clear the matrix so it is a good programming practice to call the function `clearMatrix();` at the bottom as defined above, while remaining inside the do-while loop.